# I need to force IE 6, 7, and 8 wait until CSS is loaded before rendering the page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, html

I have a responsive website I am building http://50.97.104.102/~topdog/. Since the desktop css appears at the bottom of the stylesheet the page is rendered for half a second in the mobile layout (logo appears in the center). Then switches to the desktop format. This only happens in IE 6, 7, and 8. It is a very subtle issue that only last for half a second. Most modern browsers (I use chrome) seem to wait until all the css is loaded before rendering the page.

Is there a way to force IE 6,7 and 8 to wait until the whole CSS file is loaded before rendering the page? Preferably without javascript.

Comment: Have you tried putting the CSS at the top when you serve to IE?

Comment: Have you tried putting the css at the top period. If your using media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS

```
body {
  visibility: hidden;
}
body.finished {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

And from the onload handler add a finished class to the body.

This won't work without JS. If you want this to work without JS, you can do the following which will have the flickering, if JS is disabled, but will remove the flicker if JS is enabled.

```
body.not-ready{
   visibility: hidden;
}

<body>
<script>
  $(document.body).addClass('not-ready');
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(document.body).removeClass('not-ready')
  });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Won't even have to do JS. He could just put the first declaration at the top, and the second declaration at the very bottom. It sounds to me like he only has one stylesheet, so it's not an issue of conflicting stylesheets.

Comment: If JavaScript is disabled, the page will be forever hidden.

Comment: Juan, That sounds like a good idea but I would like the site to function without js. If I add the .finished class to the body via js that would make everything hidden if js was off. Nix, I like your idea. It seems to work.

Comment: @Stratus3D Added a solution with graceful degradation, that is, it solves the problem with JS, but still shows the page if JS is off

Comment: Jaun Mendes, The first line of your js should go in the <head> (before the body has even begun to load). Also for best performance you should not be relying on jQuery to hide the body. jQuery might be loaded in the footer.

Comment: @Stratus3D: I only used `jQuery` for simplicity. I need to add a disclaimer: "Code is not ready for cut/paste, it's just to show the concept"